# Cannot install Flash player after adding nonfree repos

Tags: debian

I know this is a common problem for new users in Debian [I'm using Jessie]. I have tried following the steps on the Debian wiki [here](https://wiki.debian.org/FlashPlayer) to install Flash after adding the nonfree repos with no luck. Here is my sources files, which, I'll admit, is a bit of a mess:

```
#deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 8 _Jessie_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170116-23:46]/ jessie main 

#deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 8 _Jessie_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170116-23:46]/ jessie main 

deb http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free

#deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main 
#deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main 

# jessie-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main 
deb-src http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main 



deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ jessie main non-free contrib 
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ jessie main non-free contrib 
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib non-free 
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib non-free 
deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free 

deb http://deb.opera.com/opera-stable/ stable non-free 

#deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie main 
#deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie main 

#deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main 
#deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main 

#deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main 
#deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main 


deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free 
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free 

deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib non-free 
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib non-free 

deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/no1wantdthisname/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/no1wantdthisname/ppa/ubuntu trusty main

deb http://http.debian.net/debian jessie-backports main contrib
```

Now I tried installing pepperflash from the guide [here](https://wiki.debian.org/PepperFlashPlayer/Installing). The output of `apt-cache policy flashplugin-nonfree` gives

```
flashplugin-nonfree:
  Installed: 1:3.6.1+deb8u1
  Candidate: 1:3.6.1+deb8u1
  Version table:
 *** 1:3.6.1+deb8u1 0
        500 http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ jessie/contrib amd64 Packages
        500 http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ jessie/contrib amd64 Packages
        500 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/contrib amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

But still nothing works. I am determined to sort this out but maybe am looking in the wrong places?

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: @StephenKitt Opera, though I also tried on Firefox. It says I need the Fresh player, but apparently that is already installed...

Answer (score 1):

Wrong flash. `apt purge flashplugin-nonfree` after that you can install the right flash as it is described in your Link. `apt install pepperflashplugin-nonfree browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash` Maybe you must activate the plugin in your browser. I don't use flash so I am not sure.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I just get this though Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
pepperflashplugin-nonfree is already the newest version.
pepperflashplugin-nonfree set to manually installed.
browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash is already the newest version.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have an answer to this, but it's not a solution. Turns out the plugins are broken at the moment and are not yet fixed by the Debian team.

http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=131956#p638190

Seems for now the only thing to do if one wants to use Flash to watch videos [I won't even get into installing it globally] is to use Chromium browser, which comes with it already installed.